# General Timer Class in Android with callback fucntion

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I am trying to make a general class that I can use a timer in my application.

I want to pass through to it a function which it must run on the UI thread, as this timer will mostly be used for GUI.

This is what I have so far, however I am not sure how to implement the callback section of it, and I am having trouble with the runOnUiThread because if I pass through a context it wants me to cast it to an activity type. However I want to be able to calls this timer class from any activity.

Here is my class:

```
public class AutoTimer extends Timer {

Timer autoRefreshTimer;
TimerTask task;

public AutoTimer(int delay, int period, Context context) { // todo add
                                                            // callback as
                                                            // param

    autoRefreshTimer = new Timer();
    createTask(context);
    autoRefreshTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
}

private void createTask(final Context context) {
    task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*
             * context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             * 
             * @Override public void run() { //run callback method from the
             * calling activity } });
             */

        }
    };
}
}
```

Could you possibly help me out with my two issues.

So I wish to call it as follows:

AutoTimer timer = new AutoTimer(0,1000,Activity.this,callbackfuntion());

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the stock [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class.

Comment: How do I make the time run indefinitely? I don't want to countdown.

Comment: You can start again in onFinish()